# Faulty Assembly Logic?

Tags: assembly, x86, logic, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to write a compiler for my custom language, and the output is NASM Assembly:

```
BITS 64
section .text
    global _start

_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp,rsp

    ; --- (+) 1, 1 --- ;
    mov rax,1
    mov rbx,1
    add rax,rbx

    ; --- (if) rax --- ;
    cmp rax,0
    jz after_if_1

    ; --- (write) '3 --- ;
    mov ecx,str_3
    mov rdx,15
    mov rbx,1
    mov rax,4
    int 80h

    ; --- (+) 2, 2 --- ;
    mov rax,2
    mov rbx,2
    add rax,rbx

    ; --- (if) rax --- ;
    cmp rax,0
    jz after_if_2

    ; --- (write) '2 --- ;
    mov ecx,str_2
    mov rdx,15
    mov rbx,1
    mov rax,4
    int 80h

    ; --- (+) 3, 3 --- ;
    mov rax,3
    mov rbx,3
    add rax,rbx

    ; --- (if) rax --- ;
    cmp rax,0
    jz after_if_3

    ; --- (write) '1 --- ;
    mov ecx,str_1
    mov rdx,15
    mov rbx,1
    mov rax,4
    int 80h

after_if_3:
after_if_2:
after_if_1:
    pop rbp
    mov rax,1
    syscall

section .data
    str_1 db 33h,2bh,33h,20h,69h,73h,20h,6eh,6fh,74h,20h,7ah,65h,72h,6fh
    str_2 db 32h,2bh,32h,20h,69h,73h,20h,6eh,6fh,74h,20h,7ah,65h,72h,6fh
    str_3 db 31h,2bh,31h,20h,69h,73h,20h,6eh,6fh,74h,20h,7ah,65h,72h,6fh
```

I'm no expert in assembly, and why it always skips to the end? (jz after_if_1 gets triggered even though rax isn't zero) This is almost certainly my fault, but why?

**NOTE**: when I change the first "cmp rax,0" to "cmp eax,0" it magically worked as intended. This is confusing.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see an obvious problem with the generated code - from that I agree that it should work (i.e. not jump to `after_if_1 gets`).

Comment: `cmp rax, 0` includes a REX prefix. This would be interpreted, albeit wrongly, if your code executes in 32-bit mode. You're using a `bits 64` directive. Are you sure your NASM output format and the linker and loaders you are using are all 64-bits, not 32? The REX prefix of `cmp rax, 0` is 48h which decodes as `dec eax` in 32-bit mode. That would explain your result.

Comment: Your program as assembled by NASM is interpreted in a 32-bit code segment as: `mov eax,0x1` \ `mov ebx,0x1` \ `dec eax` \ `add eax,ebx` \ `dec eax` \ `cmp eax,byte +0x0` - The `mov` instructions are optimised by NASM which is why they do not have REX prefixes. The prefixes for `add` and `cmp` happen to make `eax` equal 0.

Comment: Never use `bits 32` or `bits 64` unless you're making a flat binary, or are writing a kernel that switches modes.  Otherwise, `nasm -felf32` implies BITS 32, and assembling 64-bit machine code into a 32-bit executable will just make confusing problems like ecm explained.